# Highcharts/Highstock jumping labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to represent multi-series events on a timeline using a column chart in Highstock.  For some reason, the labels on the x-Axis keep jumping around as the data is scrolled:

Prior to scroll (note label "Feb 2014" is attached to short column):
[image: Prior to scroll (note label "Feb 2014" is attached to short column)]

After scroll (label "Feb 2014" has jumped to a different column):
[image: After scroll (label "Feb 2014" has jumped to a different column)]

jsFiddle: [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/whiletrue/s6BmC/9/)

Highcharts.stockChart configuration:

```
chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
    chart: {
        alignTicks: true,
        animation: true,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        events: {
            load: function (e) {
                this.xAxis[0].setExtremes(1398859200000, 1414753200000);
            }
        },
        ignoreHiddenSeries: true,
        renderTo: $('#chart')[0]
    },
    colors: [
        '#89f1a4',
        '#68d9f7',
        '#9eb9ef',
        '#c49eef'
    ],
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'center',
        borderWidth: 0,
        enabled: true,
        navigation: {
            animation: true
        },
        shadow: false,
        verticalAlign: 'top'
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        enabled: false
    },
    scrollbar: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    tooltip: {
        crosshairs: false,
        shared: true
    },
    navigator: {
        height: 40,
        margin: 10,
        maskFill: 'rgba(233, 233, 233, 0.7)',
        outlineWidth: 0,
        series: {
            type: 'column',
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataGrouping: {
                enabled: true,
                forced: true,
                units: [[
                    'week',
                    [1]
                ]]
            }
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            showInLegend: true,
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataGrouping: {
                enabled: true,
                forced: true,
                units: [[
                    'week',
                    [1]
                ]]
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        max: 24,
        min: 0,
        ordinal: false
    },
    xAxis: {
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            millisecond: '%H:%M:%S.%L',
            second: '%H:%M:%S',
            minute: '%H:%M',
            hour: '%H:%M',
            day: '%e. %b',
            week: '%b %Y',
            month: '%b %Y',
            year: '%Y'
        },
        labels: {
            style: {
                color: '#ccc'
            }
        },
        minRange: 604800000,
        ordinal: false
    },
    series: data
});
```

**My question:**

Is there any way to keep the labels aligned with the columns as the chart is SCROLLED, only allowing the labels to re-order/jump around when the VIEWING RANGE is adjusted (via the navigator) ?

Comment: Have you tried to use pointRange parameter? http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.pointRange

Comment: you don't have a problem, that's simply because of timeline

Comment: tinybyte: I do have a problem - I can't get this library to behave the way I'd expect.  I'm 98% of the way there.  But thanks for your helpful comment.  @SebastianBochan: pointRange doesn't seem to change anything, regardless of its value.. could that have something to do with the stacking or grouping?

Comment: You need to use tickPositioner and return data accorting do processingData. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner